# Why doesn't declaring a variable with the same name outside and inside a loop produce an error?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, scope

```
{  
    int i;  
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)  
    {  
        int i=10;  
        printf("%d",i);  
    }  
}
```

I have two questions

1. Why is there no redeclaration error for `i`?
2. why output will be `10` 5 times and not `10` 1 time?

Comment: @Eregrith: all versions of C (don't really know about pre-C89) allowed declarations at the beginning of a block. The posted code is valid C89.

Comment: @Eregrith You're wrong. All declarations in OPs code are at the beginnings of blocks, just as C89 requires it.

Comment: Ah yes maybe. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all has to do with the *scope* of an identifier. An identifier is simply a name given to an entity (object, function, typedef name and so on) in C and, as per `C11 6.2.1 /1`:

> The same identifier can denote different entities at different points in the program.

The scope of an entity is described in `/2` of that section:

> For each different entity that an identifier designates, the identifier is visible (i.e., can be used) only within a region of program text called its scope.

And `/4` covers your specific case:

> If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope).

In other words, something like:

```
{
    int i = 42;
    printf ("%d ", i);
    {
        int i = 17;
        printf ("%d ", i);
    }
    printf ("%d\n", i);
}
```

is perfectly valid, and will print `42 17 42`. That's because the identifier `i` inside the inner block is in its *own* scope, which ends at the first closing brace.

In your particular case, you can think of it as:

```
{
    int i;              \
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)     > outer i scope
    {                   /
        int i=10;       \
        printf("%d",i);  > inner i scope
    }                   /
}
```

The inner `int i=10` effective hides the outer `i` for the duration of the body of the `for` loop. That's why it prints a lot of `10`s rather than `0..4`.

The scope of the inner `i` finishes at the closing brace of the `for` loop body so that, when the continuation condition of the `for` loop is checked, it once again sees the outer `i`. That's why it loops five times rather than once.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

- `int i;` is in outer block scope.
- `int i=10;` is in the inner block scope for the `for` loop

If we visualize the same, we can come up with something like'

```
{                   //---------------------------|
    int i;                                       |
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)                             |
    {                                            |
        int i=10;       //-------| inner scope   |> Outer scope
        printf("%d",i); //-------|               |
    }                                            |
}                  //----------------------------|
```

The case here is, the *inner* `i` will *shadow* the outer `i`. These two are *considered* seperate variable (*based on their scope*).

In other words, the `i` which is defined and present inside the *block* (inner scope) will have more preference (over the variable in outer scope). So, the inner `i` value will get printed.

OTOH, the loop counter variable `i` remains at the outer scope. It's value is not altered through the assignement inside the block. So, rightly it loops for 5 times, as asked.

Related: From `C11` standard, chapter §6.2.1, paragraph 4,

> *..[..]..* If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the *inner scope*) will end strictly before the scope of the other entity (the *outer scope*). Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is *hidden* (and not visible) within the inner scope.

So, to answer your questions,

> *Why is there no redeclaration error for i?*

Because two `i`s are treated as *seperate variable*, despite being named same.

> *why output will be `10` 5 times and not `10` 1 time?*

Because, the outer `i`, used as the counter, is not changed from inside the loop, only the loop increment condition is altering that value.

Comment: Sourav, minor change needed, only label names have function scope, as per paragraph 3. The `int i` is block scope for the function block in the same way `int i=10` is block scope for the `for` block.

Comment: @paxdiablo Sir, thank you for pointing that out. Modified the answer, please review once. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't re-declaring i since  the second declaration of i ( 'int i =10' ) is inside a loop .  That's means that in your example the variable is destroyed and recreated for each iteration of the loop .

The scope of variables created in any compound statement is limited to the compound statement itself .

Ps : If you wanted to stop the loop by changing the value of i

```
{  
int i;  
for(i=0;i<5;i++)  
{  
i=10;  
printf("%d",i);  
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ask your compiler nicely (`gcc -Wshadow`) it will warn you

```
 echo -e '#include <stdio.h>\nvoid f(void) { int i; for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { int i = 10; printf("%d", i); } }' | gcc -Wshadow -xc -c -
```

```
<stdin>: In function 'f':
<stdin>:2:53: warning: declaration of 'i' shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
<stdin>:2:20: note: shadowed declaration is here
```